# Sum Each Row in Array (Google Sheets)

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, counting

I have a complex formula the produces an Array (10+rows and 10+columns).
For simplicity's sake, let's just say it's `=unique(a1:z10)`

I'm looking for a formula that can `counta()` each Row of the array individually. It should basically return a 1-column array that counts the number of values in each row.
Because I will then wrap that in a `max()` function to see the highest count among them all.

Thanks guys. I hope my question is intelligible.
Let me know if further clarification needed.

Comment: Can you share an example google sheet, maybe with dummy numbers?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 2):

The standard way of getting row totals of an m rows by n columns array is

```
=mmult(<array>,<colvector>)
```

where `<array>` is an array of numbers and `<colvector>` is an array n rows high and one column wide containing all ones.

The standard way of getting `<colvector>` for a range is

```
=row(<range>)^0
```

but this doesn't work for an array because you can only use the row function with a range.

So I think you'd have to generate `<colvector>` another way - the easiest way is to use Sequence, but unfortunately it means repeating the formula for your `<array>` to get the column count.

**Example**

Supposing we choose this as our complex array:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(mod(sequence(10,10),8),"",sequence(10,10)))
```

a 10 X 10 array with some spaces in it.

The whole formula to get the row counts would be:

```
=ArrayFormula(mmult(n(if(mod(sequence(10,10),8),"",sequence(10,10))<>""),
sequence(columns(if(mod(sequence(10,10),7),"",sequence(10,10))))^0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(IFERROR(LEN(B:K)/LEN(B:K), 0), TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B:K)^0))))
```

[image: 0]

if you want to do it all in one step use:

```
=MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(IFERROR(LEN(B:K)/LEN(B:K), 0), 
 ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&TRANSPOSE(COLUMNS(B:K))))^0)))
```

where you replace **B:K** ranges with your formula that outputs the array